# React : Animation timing through states and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, use-effect

I try to handle game's computer side inputs through an array. Each element in the array will be set as the state 'currentTarget' to trigger the animation in child components. I think that my approach is probably wrong, anyway I wonder if there is a mean to use the setTimeout on each element of my IAInputsQueue state.

This is my non-working code :

Parent logic :

```
useEffect(()=>{
        if(!isPlayerTurn){
            
            IAInputsQueue.forEach((element, index) => {
                    window.setTimeout(() =>{
                    setCurrentTarget && setCurrentTarget(element) //Typescript checking
                },index *1000)
            });

            return () => IAInputsQueue.forEach(clearTimeout)
        }
    },[isPlayerTurn, IAInputsQueue, setCurrentTarget])
```

Child logic:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(currentTarget === uid){
            animeButton()
            musicPlay()
        }
    },[currentTarget, uid, musicPlay, animeButton])
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is the current behaviour and what is it you expect it to do?

Comment: So far I can tell you that clearTimeout needs a timeout id to work. The setTimeout function returns an id that you can later use to clear the timeout. `const timeoutIds = IAInputQueue.map((element, index) => setTimeout(...)); return () => timeoutIds.forEach(clearTimeout)`